# Flink not starting TaskManagers on Kubernetes, job reached global-terminal state

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I have deployed a Flink cluster to Kubrnetes and I only see the JobManagers running.

I had Flink running on another Kubernetes cluster where I did a SavePoint using the FlinkDeployment from the Flink Operator. The Savepoint was saved correctly. I then deployed the Flink app to the new Kubernetes cluster and patched the savepointLocationPath in FlinkDeployment.

The Flink pods now log this error

```
│ WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher - Ignoring JobGraph submission 'Windchill ESI Post Processing' because the job already reached a globally-terminal state (i.e. FAILED, CANCELED, FINISHED) in a previous execution.
...
│ io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.resourcelock.LockException: Unable to update ConfigMapLock 
...
│ Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: PUT at: https://10.0.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/post-processing-int2/configmaps/post-processing-cluster-c │
│ onfig-map. Message: Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "post-processing-cluster-config-map": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and tr │
│ y again. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=configmaps, name=post-processing-cluster-config-map, retryAfterSeconds=null, u │
│ id=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "post-processing-cluster-config-map": the object has been modified; please apply your  │
│ changes to the latest version and try again, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Conflict, st │
│ atus=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

The ConfgiMap mentioned in the error is present.

My question is how do I start a new TaskManager now? I have `numberOfTaskSlots: 4` set. I tried shelling into a JobManager pod and running `bin/taskmanager.sh start` but this just started a process in the pod which doesn't seem correct to me. I then stopped it.

I am expecting to see a new TaskManager pod start up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The clue was in the first line of the logs

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher - Ignoring JobGraph submission 'Windchill ESI Post Processing' because the job already reached a globally-terminal state (i.e. FAILED, CANCELED, FINISHED) in a previous execution
```

My mistake started with this command

```
kubectl patch flinkdeployment/<name-of-flink-deployment> --type=merge -p '{"spec": {"job": {"state": "suspended", "upgradeMode": "savepoint"}}}'
```

The problem was the `upgradeMode`. That should not have been edited and left as `last-state`. Last state tells the Flink deployment to start from where it left off using the HA state (which is state stored in Azure Blob Storage in my case). `savepoint` will put the deployment in a `FINISHED` state and will not start a new TaskManager upon deployment.

Below is the correct edit

```
kubectl patch flinkdeployment/<name-of-flink-deployment> --type=merge -p '{"spec": {"job": {"state": "suspended"}}}'
```